# How to translate this query into ActiveRecord (Rails 5)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an SQL query like the following:

```
SELECT user_id, group_id
    FROM boats
    WHERE is_docked = 1
    AND (
      dock_id IS NULL
      OR
      dock_2_id IS NULL
    )
```

The closest I got to doing it in ActiveRecord is:

```
Boat.where(is_docked: 1).where(dock_id: nil).or(Boat.where(dock_id_2:nil))
```

The SQL syntax generated from the above isn't what I expected. What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Boat.where('is_docked = ? AND (dock_id IS NULL OR dock_2_id IS NULL)', 1,).select(:property_id, :player_id)
```

Or

#### Update Boat Model

```
class Boat < ApplicationRecord
  scope :docked, -> { where('is_docked = ?', 1 }
  scope :with_unassigned_dock, -> { where('dock_id IS NULL OR dock_2_id IS NULL') }
end
```

#### new query

```
Boat.docked.with_unassigned_dock.select(:property_id, :player_id)
```